# How to share a class definition between Java and C#

Tags: java, c#

I have two projects that are working together. They are Java & C# respectively. Back-end is Java, and front-end is C#. They are talking each other with REST API. Since they are two different programming languages, now I have to define some common class twice, for two projects, which is redundant by any means.

What I am looking for is a class/struct that could used be both projects. All the members are either string or int. For example,

```
class Person
{
    int age;
    String name;
    String grade;
};
```

My first preference is something like idl (a file can be compiled in both projects). If it is not possible, during compiling time, conversion from one language to another is also acceptable, given that the conversion is free and can be used in enterprise code depot without legal implications.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is stopping you from using IDL?

Comment: @curob He does not know how to do it is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option: write the classes in Java, use [ikvmc](https://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/wiki/Ikvmc/) from the IKVM tools to produce .NET code for them.

Answer (score 0):

I have used IDL on several Java projects in order to inter operate with other system components that were written in C (not C#).

I did the following:

1. Download and install the JacORB (http://www.jacorb.org/)
2. Put the IDL compiler (**idl.bat**) on my path
3. Create an IDL file that defines my shared type.

   ```
   module com {
   module my {
   module package {
       struct Person {
           int age;
           String name;
           String grade;
       };
   };
   };
   };
   ```
4. Run the IDL compiler: `idl.bat -genEnhanced -d {outputDir} {path/to/myFile.idl}`

This should get you the Java version of the file (the Java file can be used as any other Java file you have). Doing some quick digging indicates that [iiop-net](http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/doc/dotmugs04/iiop_dotmugs04_talk.pdf)  provides similar compiler functionality for C# (again, I have not used the C# IDL compiler, just the Java one).

Answer (score 0):

Create an XSD definition and use the correct tools (xjc in Java, don't remember the .NET) to create the object on each platform.  Supports many, many platforms, though there are some slight discrepancies with how different data types are handled, especially collections, but it is possible to write an XSD definition that works for everything.  Even if you're not serializing, it gives you a language-independent definition.